# access mongodb retuned data from another function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am accessing Mongodb with node js. I have a function `test()` that when called with an argument `fruitName` it returns the number of calories from the database. How can I access the returned data from another function? Thanks in advance

```js
function test(fruitName) {
  Users.find()
    .then(async(result) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i].fruitName == fruitName) {
          //to be accessed on another function
          return result[i].calories
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}

async function myRes() {
  const result = await test('apple')
  //print calories from db
  console.log(result)
}

myRes()
```